# Checking if session has expired in Spring Webflux/Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

Is it possible to have an endpoint to check if a user session is alive without touching the session timeout. The use case is that I want to check from the frontend if there is an active session in the backend. However my current solution is to have a `keepAlive` endpoint with `.authenticated()` check on.
However this refreshes my session each time I call the endpoint giving me 30 additional minutes of session time.

Comment: Do you know where I can configure the 30 minutes before the session will timeout? I have webflux with spring boot 2.5.3 and netty. I cannot find where spring security will timeout the session after 30 minutes and how I could configure it.

Answer (score 1):

With default security filter chain sessions are contolled by `ConcurrentSessionFilter`. You can make a subclass of it, override `doFilter` method and ignore session update in particular cases.

Comment: ConcurrentSessionFilter is not used by web flux